# Performance of sequential stream

Tags: java-stream

I read the "when to use parallel stream?" by DougLea et.al http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/StreamParallelGuidance.html.

I wonder did any one had a guide lines(do's/ don't dos)/ observations which felt them that old way of coding is better in some cases than sequential stream?
I found one here https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html

I know it's a abstract question but it will be helpful if somebody can share their experience in performance of seq stream vs java 7 way

Answer (score 1):

I've done this just a few days ago; we had to sum a very large array and was wondering what would be the fastest way to do it - so I measured (don't guess; I've used `jmh`):

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class Holder {

    @Param({ "1000", "10000", "50000", "100000", "1000000" })
    public int howManyEntries;

    int array[] = null;

    @Setup
    public void setUp() {
        array = new int[howManyEntries];
        for (int i = 0; i < howManyEntries; ++i) {
            array[i] = i;
        }
    }

    @TearDown
    public void tearDown() {
        array = null;
    }
}

@Fork(1)
@Benchmark
public int iterative(Holder holder) {

    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < holder.howManyEntries; ++i) {
        total += holder.array[i];
    }

    return total;
}

@Fork(1)
@Benchmark
public int stream(Holder holder) {
    return Arrays.stream(holder.array).sum();
}

@Fork(1)
@Benchmark
public int streamParallel(Holder holder) {
    return Arrays.stream(holder.array).parallel().sum();
}
```

The winner is **always** the old style java-7 way.

```
// 1000=[iterative, stream, streamParallel]
// 10000=[iterative, stream, streamParallel]
// 50000=[iterative, stream, streamParallel]
// 100000=[iterative, stream, streamParallel]
// 1000000=[iterative, stream, streamParallel]
```

Even for 1 million elements.  But the result differs in up to 60 ms - if that bites you or not is entirely your choice.

Streams are not meant for speed, they will not replace the old style, neither do they want to - it could add extra visibility to your code for example.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it.  I understood the code readability provided by stream way. Now a days, I had a tendency to write everything in the stream way but on an introspection I found that I should have use the old style in some place for  better performance. That's why I am looking for real life do's and don't do's

Comment: @nantitv I get your pain to be honest; but the part about code being more readable has grown so big on me - I really have a harder time reading pre java-8 code with streams, that even those milliseconds can't make it... This, of course,  does not matter (the speed loss), until it does - may be that is what you got "hit" with...